# Calculate row insertion time difference

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

For example if I have id and timestamp in mysql table. It contains several records. How to I find and store each row insertion time difference in php, i.e. compare the insertion time of  row 2 with row 1 and store result, compare row 3 with row 2 and store result.......

I have table in the name of messages, the fields are

```
id int(11), 
timestamp int(11),
body_xml text, 
chatname text
```

This table contains chat informations, and I need to find the total chat time and no. of conversation available for particular user using id. So I want to find each row time difference, if time difference exists more than 10 mins, It consider as new conversation.

My task is to find total chat time about particular user and no. of conversation available for that user in skype.

Now I store all chat information into mysql table.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  timestamp           message     name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2012-10-11 11:18:34     hi          ram
2   2012-10-11 11:19:14     hw r u      ram
3   2012-10-11 11:20:55     fine        ram
4   2012-10-11 11:55:03     r u there   ram
5   2012-10-11 11:56:21     yes         ram
6   2012-10-11 11:57:33     then        ram
```

in the above table id 1 to 3 have less than 10 mins time difference, but id 4 have more than 10 mins time difference from id 3, so here it will consider as new conversation, store total time of id 1 to 3 into varable and upadate total time of 4 to 6 into same varable, here total conversation is 2.

I need output as 
Total No. of converation 2
Total Time is xx:xx

**I tried this code**

```
SELECT A.id, A.timestamp, (B.timestamp - A.timestamp) AS timedifference
FROM time_diff A CROSS JOIN time_diff B WHERE B.id IN (SELECT MIN (C.id) FROM time_diff C WHERE C.id > A.timestamp)
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

**I got null result**

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Please show the query that does not work.

Comment: Can u show what have u tried yet?

Comment: I dont any idea about this...

Comment: @Gapchoos Can we please stop using textspeak? How hard is it to spell out "you"? It's just two more characters, for goodness' sake.

Comment: So basically, you have no idea how to program and you came here to ask for someone to do it for free or?

Comment: not like that @N.B. I am a developer, my current task is to find total time and no. of conversion for particular skype user. I completed to convert the skype chat data into mysql table. But now I am so confused how to calculate difference row by row... so I need others help

Comment: @PraveenKumar You have to remove the space between `MIN` and `(`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here are the steps:

1. google `ALTER TABLE` mysql, if you have to add a row for the time difference
2. google about joins, or this **[link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)** is pretty good. Why? You want to join your table with itself based on the `id` column, but with `id+1` on one side. If the id is not a straight sequence you can do it like this: `select r1.* 
   , (select max(`timestamp`) from yourTable r2 where r1.id > r2.id)
   from yourTable r1`
3. Read about **[timestampdiff() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)**
4. Create a SQL `SELECT` statement when you have understood steps 2 and 3 and see if it gets you what you want.
5. When step 4 is what you want, you transform this `SELECT` statement into an `UPDATE` statement.
6. The rest of the calculations are better done in PHP.
7. When there are still questions left come back and we will be happy to help you (if you showed some effort :) )

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the id field in the table does not have squance order, id likes 211,235,700...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I Got the solutions for this issue thank you!!!!!